# How can I restrict item number to item name

Tags: 2010, infopath, infopath-rules

I would like to do something similar to this [how-to](https://salnikan.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/prevention-of-duplicate-entries-based-on-two-or-more-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list/), but with a twist.

```
| Item Name     | Item Number   | Store | Quantity |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:| --------:|
| Red Apple     |               | ABC1  |  0       |
| Green Apple   |               | ABC1  | 12       |
| Red Apple     | 980-90-001    | ABC2  |  6       |
| Green Apple   | 980-90-002    | ABC2  |  8       |
| Red Apple     | 980-90-002    | ABC3  | 12       |<--
| Green Apple   | 980-90-002    | ABC3  | 13       |
| New Red Apple | 980-90-003    | ABC1  |  9       |
```

I would like to only allow a user to use matching pairs excluding blank fields. Therefore the line item `Red Apple` with `Item Number` `980-90-002` would not be allowed. I'm not sure how about getting this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by making some minor changes to Andrej Salnik's [post](https://salnikan.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/prevention-of-duplicate-entries-based-on-two-or-more-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list/)

See Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJNqm.png) and Image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkOqH.png) for details.